# ReactJS Testing: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write my first ever test for my code, and I am having trouble just getting the very basics to work. Here's what I have:

```
//namePlate.js
import React from 'react';

const NamePlate = (props)=>(
  <div className = 'namePlate' style = {props.color(props.name)}>
    {props.name}
    <button id = {props.id} type = 'button' onClick = {props.onClick}>x</button>}
  </div>
)

export default NamePlate

//namePlate.test.js

import React from 'react';
import NamePlate from './namePlate.js';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';


it('renders', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<NamePlate name = 'Test' id = '1' onClick ={() =>{}} color = {()=>{}}/>);
  expect(wrapper.find('div')).to.have.lengthOf(1);

})
```

I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined," and I am really unsure of what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expect(wrapper.find('div')).toHaveLength(1);
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavelengthnumber